# Html.BeginForm and Ajax.BeginForm in same view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm planning to add file upload using ajax and form submission in same view

```
@model project_name.Models.ProductFinanceFeatures

@{
 }

<h2>--------File_Upload-------------</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Financing_Product_Feature_Upload", "FileUpload", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="file" name="files">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
}    

<h2>-------Form_Submission-----</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()   

    <div class="form-horizontal">          
          ......                  
    </div>
}
```

this is my controller class method for ajax

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Financing_Product_Feature_Upload(HttpPostedFileBase files)
    {
      ...
    }
```

once I select a file and click "upload" button ,then I debug this I can see `files` value become `null`

Comment: You cannot use `Ajax.BeginForm()` to upload files. You need to use `FormData` Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) for one way

Comment: Actually its bit hard for me to understand what should include , view and controller classes , as I understood , ajax postback function should be under section script of viewpage , other things bit unclear for me ,

Comment: You don't need to include anything else. Read my first comment - you **CANNOT** use `Ajax.BeginForm()` to upload a file

Comment: what should I remove on my view then ? how to trigger this ajax function ?

Comment: You can just use a `<form>` tag with the file input and a button and handle the button's click event to call the `$.ajax()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke I created as you guided , but once I debug it cannot direct to `Financing_Product_Feature_Upload` here the [code](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/prg9G)

Comment: First you need to use a `<button type="button"` (or add `return false;` in the click handler so you cancel the default submit). Next you need to set the value of `formData` - e.g. `var formdata = new FormData($('#fileform').get(0));` and give the first form `id="fileform"`

Comment: where should I include this `var formdata = new FormData($('#fileform').get(0));` ? inside controller or under ajax function ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107610/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Comment: @StephenMuecke now seems like okay
inside the method I have a conditon like following
`if (Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0){..`
when I debug I can see file is transporting ,
but when It comes to above condition it cannot give me `true` or `false`